# Excel Power Query from ODBC with 3 tables

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have 3 queries, WORKS, MATERIALS and TOOLS and I want to show the RESULT of each WORK in a sheet in excel as follows:

**WORKS**

```
ID  DATE        DESCRIPTION TIME
1   31/10/2022  XXXXXXXX1   2:00
2   31/10/2022  XXXXXXXX2   4:00
3   31/10/2022  XXXXXXXX3   1:00
```

**MATERIALS**

```
ID  WORK_ID NAME    QUANTITY
1   1       SCREW   20
2   1       PAINT   1
3   2       PAINT   2
4   2       STAPLE  40
5   3       PAINT   1
6   1       STAPLE  30
7   3       SCREW   5
8   2       SCREW   1
```

**TOOLS**

```
ID  WORK_ID NAME    TIME
1   1       STAPLER 1:00
2   2       STAPLER 2:00
```

**RESULT**

```
1   31/10/2022  XXXXXXXX1   2:00
                SCREW       20
                PAINT       1
                STAPLE      30
                STAPLER     1:00
2   31/10/2022  XXXXXXXX2   4:00
                PAINT       2
                STAPLE      40
                SCREW       1
                STAPLER     2:00
3   31/10/2022  XXXXXXXX3   1:00
                PAINT       1
                SCREW       5
```

the result is a sample of what I need, the design may be different but with the information shown in the example.

Example Excel: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnYimXo7OdOygfNLd_hi-ZI-BuUvBw?e=HHIBXA

The problem is that in the pivot table it shows me not only the values of each work.

Thanks

Comment: So: what's the problem? What have you tried so far (post your code), what error message(s) are you getting, which specific issue are you seeking help with?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to attach the example excel, I just added it. In the sheet Hoja1 I can't show what I want as a result

Comment: You've described a requirement. But you haven't explained what's preventing you from fulfilling that requirement - what's your specific issue?

Comment: The problem is that it is not displaying what I want in the pivot table. I would like to show what I have in the RESULT sheet in the pivot table of Hoja1, but it shows me all the values of all the work in each work, instead of just its own.

Answer (score 3):

In powerquery, change some column names so they stack better, then combine the tables and sort them using code similar to:

```
let combined = Table.AddIndexColumn(works, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type) 
    & Table.AddIndexColumn(materials, "Index", 9999, 1, Int64.Type) 
    & Table.AddIndexColumn(tools, "Index", 99999, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(combined,{{"ID", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}})
in combined
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new with power query and I'm a bit lost and I don't understand very well your possible solution. Can you help me with me example Excel?

Comment: Use your file. Go into power query. Home advanced editor. Paste above